# How to use laravel notifications for serialized models in a cross database setup?

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant, distributed-database

My current setup is that `User` and `Notification` are saved to my main database, `Post`  is saved to a different database.
`User` and `Notification` db connections are:

```php
protected $connection = "main";
```

and `Post` db connections is:

```php
protected $connection = "second";
```

My notification table is saved to the main database. I have a notification class called "PostReplied" that takes a `$post` as a parameter. so it's serialized when it's queued. When it started processing this job, it's trying to get the post from the "main" database instead of `Post`'s connection "second" database.

Any suggestions on how to make the notifications work with cross-database models?

Comment: I changed my notification to take "postId" instead of the object now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Depending on what multi-tenant setup you use, it may rely on setting the connection name on the model. You could for instance set the connection for the Post model like this:

**Models/Post.php**

```php
/**
 * Get the current connection name for the model.
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getConnectionName()
{
    return 'tenant_connection';
}
```

Then you need to define a `tenant_connection` key in the `database.connections` config (`config/database.php`). I know `hyn/multitenant` does it like this (https://packagist.org/packages/hyn/multi-tenant).

#### Solution 2

One other, lesser way to do it is to switch connection on-the-go while you are creating the queries, like so:

```php
DB::setDefaultConnection('custom_connection');
Post::query()->where('status', 1)->get();

// Revert to default connection, assuming `mysql` here.
DB::setDefaultConnection('mysql');
```

This gives you more freedom but your code gets messier and I don't recommend it.

#### Solution 3

This one can also make your code harder to understand. You can incorporate the database name in your queries, like so:

```
DB::table('database1.posts as d1p')
    ->leftjoin('database2.users as d2u', 'd1p.user_id', '=', 'd2u.id');
```

You can probably mix and match this using Eloquent builder functions.

Comment: Thank you. I was implementing multi-tenancy by myself. But I can look into the first method and implement that. It's good to know about these options for the future.